# ThreadPoolExecutor vs ForkJoinPool: stealing subtasks

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor, forkjoinpool

From java docs,

> A ForkJoinPool differs from other kinds of ExecutorService mainly by virtue of employing work-stealing: all threads in the pool attempt to find and execute subtasks created by other active tasks (eventually blocking waiting for work if none exist).
>
> This enables efficient processing when most tasks spawn other subtasks (as do most ForkJoinTasks). When setting asyncMode to true in constructors, ForkJoinPools may also be appropriate for use with event-style tasks that are never joined.

After going through below [ForkJoinPool example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/java-fork-and-join-forkjoinpool.html#submittting-tasks-to-forkjoinpool), Unlike ThreadPoolExecutor, I have not seen parameter to set Queue size. I did not get clue on how ForkJoinPool stealing mechanism.

```
//creating the ThreadPoolExecutor

ThreadPoolExecutor executorPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 10, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(3000), threadFactory, rejectionHandler);
```

**Assume that I have created ThreadPoolExecutor with 10 threads and 3000 Callable tasks have been submitted. How these threads share the load of execution of sub tasks?**

**And How ForkJoin pool behaves differently for same use case?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `ForkJoinPool`, there are two kinds of queues — the pool one which you basically used when submitting a task, and the thread specific one (i.e. one for each thread). From a `ForkJoinTask` you can invoke new tasks (generally a split of your problem).

These new tasks are not offered to the pool queue but to the thread specific one. Thus, they are taken/pulled in priority to the pool one, as if you have done all the job in the same task. Furthermore, the invoker task appears to be blocked for subtask completion.

In reality, the "blocked time" is spent to consume subtasks. It will be stupid to let other threads "to loaf around" while one of them is flooded by work. So, "work stealing" takes place.

To go beyond. To be efficient, "work stealing" takes/pulls task from the opposite bound. This greatly reduces contention over queue writing.

Always in efficiency, it's better to only split the problem in two subtasks and let the subtask split again and again. Even if you know the problem must be split directly in N parts. This is because "work stealing" requires concurrent writes to a shared resource, so limit its activation and contention!

Comment: so we have two queues in ForkJoin pool? One global & other one at thread level. Stealing happens at thread level ? How to set global queue & thread task size?

Comment: two *kinds* of queue. There are the pool one and the thread one*s*. To be more precise, thread task collection is FIFO (stack). Work stealing always happens at thread one. Taking a task from the pool one is just the basic dispatch behaviour of an `Executor`. As far as I know `WorkQueue` (implementation used by ForkJoin) aren't size bound.

Answer (score 17):

If you have 3000 tasks in advance, and they are not going to spawn other tasks, the two will not behave substantially differently:  with 10 threads, 10 tasks will be run at a time until they are all done.

ForkJoinPool is designed for the case where you have one or a few tasks to start with, but the tasks know how to split themselves up into subtasks.  In this situation, ForkJoinPool is optimized to permit tasks to check on the availability of processing threads and split themselves up appropriately.

Comment: What is the mechanism to assign 3000 sub tasks to 10 threads? is it round robin & first come first serve? How can we set the same values for ForkJoinPool?

Comment: A ThreadPoolExecutor typically accepts tasks from a queue, so if the queue is first come first serve, the tasks will be processed in a roughly first come first serve manner.  How they are distributed to the threads in the thread pool depend on the specific type of pool used; you can think of it as round robin, but it doesn't really matter since tasks are necessarily given to free threads, which don't differ.  A ForkJoinPool by default executes tasks in a last in first out manner, but you can set it to be first in first out.  See the Javadoc for both classes for more detail.